# dist-upgrade crashed, all files are now in my home directory

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, updates, do-release-upgrade

I finally decided to upgrade from ubuntu 15.x to 16.x LTS on an old laptop, using the "do-release-upgrade" command. Of course things didn't went smoothly, the process has frozen somewhere near the end, probably while doing some kind of indexing of my old files.

The upgraded ubuntu version appears to work well (although only tested quickly), however all folders are given empty and it looks like all files are now in the Home directory, i.e. +500k files agglomerated in a single directory, quite a mess.

Is there any way to re-build the data-tree ? I suppose a mapping should exist somewhere.

I have tried the sequence

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg --configure -a 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Tells me that everything is fine.

Thanks

Comment: @pomsky, yep you are right, question has been corrected. And yes I took my time to upgrade , I had a lot of stuff on this computer I didn't want to mess up with.

Comment: Ok, I think I now understand what happened, and it is really bad bad. In my terminal history I had a nasty command:  "find . -mindepth 2 -type f -print -exec mv --backup=numbered {} . ;" . For whatever reason it was executed at root. Probably while hitting random keys, as I thought the terminal was frozen during update.